# How can I replace multiple slashes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "Hello\\\World\\\";
var newStr = str.replace("\\\", "");
alert(newStr); // I want this to alert: HelloWorld
```

The number of slashes is always 3, not more not less. How can I replace them? The code above doesn't work at all. I've played around a bit with the global flag, escaping the slashes etc but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want three slashes in a row in a string literal then you need to *escape* each one in turn:

```
var str = "Hello\\\\\\World\\\\\\";
var newStr = str.replace("\\\\\\", "");
```

In your current string, `\\\W` would be one slash and an error as `\W` is not a valid sequence. (Some more examples: `\\` is a single slash, `\t` a tab, `\"` a quotation character).

Comment: it will only replaced the first occurrence...u need to add global modifier..so your regex will be /\\\\\\/g..check this out..http://jsfiddle.net/RZ6TL/..

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you need to escape each slash with another backslash, as mentioned by @Bathsheba.

Additionally, you want your replacement regex to be global:

```
var str = "Hello\\\\\\World\\\\\\";
var newStr = str.replace(/\\\\\\/g, "");
alert(newStr); // I want this to alert: HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `\\\\\\` for replace

[image]

`\\` indicates `\`

> There are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), and the opening square bracket [, the opening curly brace {, These special characters are often called "*metacharacters*".

***If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash.***

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes sense now.